# How to convert my sql query to xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have xml file

```
<ServiceHotel>
    <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>1</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>21.168</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>34.195</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>1</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>25.618</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>38.645</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Single Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>25.618</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Room Only</Board>
            <RoomType>Double Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>19.840</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Bed and Breakfast</Board>
            <RoomType>Twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>34.195</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Bed and Breakfast</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>38.645</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Bed and Breakfast</Board>
            <RoomType>Single Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>25.618</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Bed and Breakfast</Board>
            <RoomType>Double Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>19.840</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Full Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>35.195</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Full Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>32.645</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Half Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>35.195</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>3</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Half Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>32.645</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Half Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Single Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>28.618</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Half Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Double Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>20.840</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
  <AvailableRoom>
        <HotelOccupancy>
        <RoomCount>1</RoomCount>
        <Occupancy>
            <AdultCount>1</AdultCount>
            <ChildCount>1</ChildCount>
        </Occupancy>
        </HotelOccupancy>
        <HotelRoom>
            <Board>Half Board</Board>
            <RoomType>Double/twin Superior</RoomType>
            <Price>
                <Amount>30.168</Amount>
            </Price>
        </HotelRoom>
  </AvailableRoom>
</ServiceHotel>
```

I convert the above xml to sql query like below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON DECLARE @Product TABLE (
Total_Adults VarChar(50) ,
Board_Type VarChar(100) , 
Room_Type VarChar(150) ,
Room_Count VarChar(10) ,
Adults VarChar(10) ,
Child VarChar(10) ,
Price Float(53) 
); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('111','Room Only','Double/twin Superior','1','1','1','21.168'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Room Only','Twin Superior','1','3','0','34.195'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('111','Room Only','Double/twin Superior','1','1','1','25.618'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Room Only','Double/twin Superior','1','3','0','38.645'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Room Only','Single Superior','1','1','0','25.618');
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Room Only','Double Superior','1','1','0','19.840'); 

INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Bed and Breakfast','Twin Superior','1','3','0','34.195'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Bed and Breakfast','Double/twin Superior','1','3','0','38.645'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Bed and Breakfast','Single Superior','1','1','0','25.618');
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Bed and Breakfast','Double Superior','1','1','0','19.840'); 

INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Full Board','Twin Superior','1','3','0','35.195'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Full Board','Double/twin Superior','1','3','0','32.645'); 

INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Half Board','Twin Superior','1','3','0','35.195'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('130','Half Board','Double/twin Superior','1','3','0','32.645'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Half Board','Single Superior','1','1','0','28.618');
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('110','Half Board','Double Superior','1','1','0','20.840'); 
INSERT INTO @Product Values ('111','Half Board','Double/twin Superior','1','1','1','30.168'); 

WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Total_Adults, Board_Type, Room_Type ORDER BY Price ASC
) AS RN, * FROM @Product)
,CTE2 AS ( SELECT * FROM CTE1 WHERE RN = 1)
,CTE3 As (Select *,Count(*) over()as Frequency 
, row_number()over(partition by Total_Adults, Board_Type order by Price ASC) as RNN from CTE2)
,CTE4 As (
select *, Count(Board_Type) over (partition by Board_Type) as RC from CTE3 where RNN=1)
Select SUM(Price) over (partition by Board_Type) as Grand_Total,* from CTE4 where RC='3' 
ORDER BY Grand_Total ASC, MIN(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY Board_Type),Board_Type,Price;
```

the output of my sql query is

```
Grand_Total, Total_Adults,  Board_Type,  Room_Type,  Room_Count,  Adults, Child, Price
75.203  110 Room Only   Double Superior           1    1    0    19.84
75.203  111 Room Only   Double/twin Superior      1    1    1    21.168
75.203  130 Room Only   Twin Superior             1    3    0    34.195
83.653  110 Half Board  Double Superior           1    1    0    20.84
83.653  111 Half Board  Double/twin Superior      1    1    1    30.168
83.653  130 Half Board  Double/twin Superior      1    3    0    32.645
```

I need to create XSL 1.0 file for taking this output. (equivalent to SQL query)

i try below query but not working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="by-board" match="AvailableRoom" use="HotelRoom/Board"/>

    <xsl:key name="by-b" match="AvailableRoom" use="concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount)"/>

  <xsl:key name="TotalAdults" match="HotelOccupancy" use="concat(Occupancy/AdultCount, '|', Occupancy/ChildCount)" />
  <xsl:variable name="TotalRoomCount" select="count(/ServiceHotel/AvailableRoom/HotelOccupancy [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('TotalAdults', concat(Occupancy/AdultCount, '|', Occupancy/ChildCount))[1])])" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  border="1">

    <tr>
        <td height="28" width="290"><font face="Arial" size="2">Room Type</font></td>
        <td height="28" width="302"><font face="Arial" size="2">Board Type</font></td>
        <td height="28" width="51" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2">R.Count</font></td>
        <td height="28" width="52" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2">A.Count</font></td>
        <td height="28" width="52" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2">C.Count</font></td>
        <td height="28" width="89" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2">Price</font></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ServiceHotel" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ServiceHotel">
      <xsl:for-each select="AvailableRoom[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-board', HotelRoom/Board)[1]) 
                             and count(key('by-board', HotelRoom/Board)) >= 
                                $TotalRoomCount 

                                ]">
        <xsl:sort select="sum(key('by-board', HotelRoom/Board)[position() &lt; 4]/HotelRoom/Price/Amount)"/>


       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="group"/>

      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AvailableRoom" mode="group">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('by-board', HotelRoom/Board)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-b', 
    concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount)
    )[1]) 
     ]">

                              <xsl:sort select="HotelRoom/Price/Amount" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>



    <tr>
        <td height="28" width="290" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="302" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="51" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="52" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="52" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="89" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('by-board', HotelRoom/Board)[position() &lt; 4] /HotelRoom/Price/Amount), '#.000')"/></font></td>
    </tr>


  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AvailableRoom">


        <tr>
        <td height="28" width="290"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="HotelRoom/RoomType"/></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="302"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="HotelRoom/Board"/></font></td>
                <td height="28" width="51" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/RoomCount"/></font></td>
                <td height="28" width="52" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount"/></font></td>
                <td height="28" width="52" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount"/></font></td>
        <td height="28" width="89" align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(HotelRoom/Price/Amount, '#.000')"/></font></td>
        </tr>        
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT is used to transform one xml document into another one. it is not a "data representation" format.

Comment: i d't no more about xsl. but i think we can make a group filter in side xsl?

Comment: What file format do you want your output to be in?

Comment: 1). Group by board + roomCount+ adult +child. 2)if board is not enough, avoid that board from the output. 3) take the cheapest rate from the board.

Comment: You haven't explained the rules that the transformation must implement -- don't expect XSLT experts to know well SQL. Please, edit the question and provide the necessary explanation (the SQL code can be omitted, because it is confusing and only takes space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are saying is that you want your XSLT to output the same table that is currently output by your example SQL.

I could achieve this by making use of the **node-set** extension function. When you 'group by' the board type, instead of just outputing the groups of rooms, the results are stored in a variable.

```
  <xsl:variable name="rooms">
     <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="//AvailableRoom
           [HotelRoom/Board = current()/HotelRoom/Board]
           [generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-b', concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount))[1])]" mode="room" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

This then allows you to exclude the **board** elements which have less than three elements in them, for example

```
<xsl:if test="count(ns:node-set($rooms)/AvailableRoom) >= 3">
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
   exclude-result-prefixes="ns">

   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="by-board" match="AvailableRoom" use="HotelRoom/Board" />
   <xsl:key name="by-b" match="AvailableRoom" use="concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount)"/>     

   <xsl:template match="/ServiceHotel">
      <table border="1">
    <tr>
          <td>Grand Total</td>
          <td>Total Adults?</td>
          <td>Board Type</td>
          <td>Room Type</td>
          <td>Room Count</td>
          <td>Adults</td>
          <td>Child</td>
          <td>Price</td>
       </tr>       
         <xsl:apply-templates select="AvailableRoom[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-board',HotelRoom/Board)[1])]" mode="board" />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AvailableRoom" mode="board">
      <xsl:variable name="rooms">
         <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="//AvailableRoom
               [HotelRoom/Board = current()/HotelRoom/Board]
               [generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-b', concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount))[1])]" mode="room" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="count(ns:node-set($rooms)/AvailableRoom) >= 3">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:node-set($rooms)/AvailableRoom">
            <xsl:with-param name="total" select="sum(ns:node-set($rooms)/AvailableRoom/HotelRoom/Price/Amount)" />
            <xsl:sort select="HotelRoom/Price/Amount" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AvailableRoom" mode="room">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('by-b', concat(HotelRoom/Board,'|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount , '|',HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount))">
         <xsl:sort select="HotelRoom/Price/Amount" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AvailableRoom">
      <xsl:param name="total" />
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($total, '0.00')" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/RoomCount"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount"/>         
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelRoom/Board"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelRoom/RoomType"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/RoomCount"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/AdultCount"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelOccupancy/Occupancy/ChildCount"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="HotelRoom/Price/Amount"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Grand Total</td>
      <td>Total Adults?</td>
      <td>Board Type</td>
      <td>Room Type</td>
      <td>Room Count</td>
      <td>Adults</td>
      <td>Child</td>
      <td>Price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>75.20</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>Room Only</td>
      <td>Double Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>19.840</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>75.20</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>Room Only</td>
      <td>Double/twin Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>21.168</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>75.20</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>Room Only</td>
      <td>Twin Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>34.195</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>83.65</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>Half Board</td>
      <td>Double Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>20.840</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>83.65</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>Half Board</td>
      <td>Double/twin Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>30.168</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>83.65</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>Half Board</td>
      <td>Double/twin Superior</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>32.645</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Do note, the extension function very much depends on what processor you are using. In this case, I am using Mircosoft, and so the name space for the extension function is urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt. If you are not using this, you will need to find which one is supported; most possibly http://exslt.org/common